# Serial downvoting on voice dictation questions

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I've just noticed that I got downvoted on my voice dictation questions:

[image]

Are voice dictation questions out of scope here? If not, is there any other issues with my  voice dictation questions?

- [Equivalent of Dragon NaturallySpeaking's HeardWord function in Dragon Dictate 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/159833/20338)
- [No cap after a period in Dragon Dictate 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/159831/20338)
- [Voice command to output "\ref{}" in Dragon Dictate 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/159829/20338)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those questions are not only on topic, but I view them as good ones. My guess is someone doesn't like questions about third party products.

I'll watch for vote patterns, but so far nothing is in "moderator needs to act" range. If you see two dozens of votes, please flag a post or bump this again and we can see if there is a pattern that would merit intervention.

You are clearly trying to use OS X software and hardware to do some useful automation and voice recognition. I hope a few cranky votes don't put you off on the site.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. I'm new on this SE so I essentially wanted to make sure the questions were all right. The serial downvoting got reversed, then was performed again, we'll see how it goes..

Comment: Seems someone didn't like them all appearing all at once & got trigger happy. I thought they were good questions too, no reason to downvote. I'm glad they all bounced back.

Comment: The system reversed one person't votes as part of the daily vote checks. Seems like things are working as intended to me...

Comment: @bmike Actually the guy did serial downvoted a few minutes after his first serial downvote got reversed: the second serial downvote didn't get reversed.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829 serial voting is defined as 20 to 100 votes in a day usually. People are allowed to vote down bad answers - so it's a matter of how many and how quickly in most cases. You got three down votes by the looks of things in your screen shot.

Comment: @bmike and 3 more very suspicious downvotes today...

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I noticed that today. All the question you've asked have been downvoted specifically.